# Vertically align the bullet image and bullet text

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, itemize

After I change the bullet symbol of an item to be an image, it seems the bottom of the image is aligned with the top of the bullet text. A minimal example below ([note.png](http://powerman.name/doc/images/icons/note.png)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{itemize}
\item[\includegraphics{note}] \blindtext
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: itemize with graphics]

I'm wondering if it is possible to top-align the image with the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using `enumitem`.  There may be a problem with the amount of whitespace surrounding your image. I left it as is because I'm not sure what your thoughts are about that, but if you trimmed the image somewhat, it might look better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[1]{labelindent=\parindent}
%\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label={%
    \raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \includegraphics{note}}}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{itemize}
\item \blindtext
\end{itemize}

% The whitespace problem
\fbox{\includegraphics{note}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may find something like `\raisebox{-0.7\height}[0pt][0pt]{...}` acceptable in this case with this image, as long as you recognize it for the hack that it is.

Comment: Thanks! I can certainly trim the white margin of the image.